# How to find a single-variable polynomial in a zero-dimensional ideal?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, computer-algebra

Given finitely many multivariate polynomials with algebraic coefficients that generate a zero-dimensional ideal, is there an easy way to find a nonzero single-variable polynomial in this ideal?

If we compute a Groebner basis in the lexicographic ordering, then the first polynomial in the resulting triangular system will do the trick, but I want an approach that takes less time.

My intuition is that a Groebner basis is not necessary here. For example, suppose the variety is empty. Then *any* nonzero single-variable polynomial will work for my purposes. Meanwhile, a Groebner basis calculation will spin its wheels to prove that the variety is empty. This is overkill!

Bonus points for a faster-than-Groebner solution that's already implemented in a standard computer algebra system.